# AWK/SEDManipulate text file, Create a CSV file using a feeding file

Tags: text, vbscript, sed, awk, wmic

I need to manipulate a text file, I created it using wmic scripts.

Original file:

```
Node,Manufacturer,Model
NAKAMA,Dell Computer Corporation,PowerEdge 6650             
Node,Name,Version
NAKAMA,Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1,5.2.3790


Node,AddressWidth
NAKAMA,32
NAKAMA,32
NAKAMA,32
NAKAMA,32


Node,SerialNumber
NAKAMA,BZJS571


Node,Name,Version
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Excel Viewer,12.0.6219.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Software Update for Web Folders  (English) 14,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Visio MUI (English) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Shared Setup Metadata MUI (English) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Visio 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Proofing (English) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Shared MUI (English) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Proof (English) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Proof (Spanish) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,Microsoft Office Proof (French) 2010,14.0.4763.1000
NAKAMA,MSXML 6 Service Pack 2 (KB954459),6.20.1099.0
NAKAMA,Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition (DTC),9.2.3042.00
NAKAMA,Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 Service Pack 2,3.2.30729
NAKAMA,Microsoft Group Policy Management Console with SP1,1.0.2.0
NAKAMA,Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 (7.1),7.1.30514
NAKAMA,Microsoft SQL Server Native Client,9.00.3042.00
NAKAMA,Broadcom Management Programs,10.38.04
NAKAMA,Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 SP1,3.5.30729
NAKAMA,Symantec Endpoint Protection,11.0.7101.1056
NAKAMA,Windows Resource Kit Tools - ClusterRecovery.exe,1.0.0.1
NAKAMA,Java(TM) 6 Update 11,6.0.110
NAKAMA,Windows Resource Kit Tools,5.2.3790
NAKAMA,ILMT-TAD4D Agent,7.2.2.1
NAKAMA,Microsoft Active Directory Topology Diagrammer,2.2.4146
NAKAMA,IBM Tivoli Storage Manager Client,05.04.0100
NAKAMA,TivReDist,1.00.0000
NAKAMA,Adobe Reader X (10.1.0),10.1.0
NAKAMA,ActivePerl 5.10.0 Build 1004,5.10.1004
NAKAMA,Active Directory Migration Tool,2.0.0.0
NAKAMA,Microsoft Easy Assist v2,8.1.6416.0
NAKAMA,Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Express Edition (SQLEXPRESS),9.2.3042.00
NAKAMA,Dell OpenManage Server Administrator,5.5.0
NAKAMA,Windows Resource Kit Tools - GPInventory.exe,1.0.1361.27800
NAKAMA,Microsoft SQL Server VSS Writer,9.00.3042.00
NAKAMA,VMware Remote Console Plug-in,2.5.0.199067
NAKAMA,Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Tools Express Edition,9.2.3042.00
NAKAMA,Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable,8.0.56336
NAKAMA,Microsoft Visual J# 2.0 Redistributable Package - SE,2.0.50728
NAKAMA,VMware vSphere Client 5.1,5.1.0.1557
NAKAMA,Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 Administration Tools Pack,5.2.3790.3959
NAKAMA,Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable - x86 9.0.30729.4148,9.0.30729.4148
NAKAMA,Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x86 Redistributable - 10.0.30319,10.0.30319
NAKAMA,Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2,2.2.30729
NAKAMA,Windows Support Tools,5.2.3790.3959
NAKAMA,Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell for Active Directory,1.5.1.2421
NAKAMA,MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB954430),4.20.9870.0
NAKAMA,Debugging Tools for Windows (x86),6.12.2.633
NAKAMA,Microsoft SQL Server Setup Support Files (English),9.00.3042.00
NAKAMA,CBMR 5.0.1 Release 4,5.0.1
```

Desired output:

```
Node,Manufacturer,Model,Name,Version,AddressWidth,SerialNumber,Name,Version
NAKAMA,Dell Computer Corporation,PowerEdge 6650,Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1,5.2.3790,32,BZJS571,CBMR 5.0.1 Release 4,5.0.1
```

The original file is separated, and I only need some parts of it. 
Each time I queried information I obtained a description of what I was querying and the result the line below it.

But now I need to organize data in this way:

First: 
Node,Manufacturer,Model : I need all that

Second: 
Node,Manufacturer,Model : I only need Manufacturer,Model (I will exclude Node from the remaining lines)

Third:
Node,AddressWidth : I only need AddressWidth (only one time will be enough)

Fourth: 
Node,SerialNumber : I only need SerialNumber

Fifth: 
Node,Name,Version : I only need Name,Version but only for line that contains CBMR

I am not sure if this is possible.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. What does the stuff about First:, Second: ... etc mean? Is it meant to be the logic you're trying to use? You have tagged a 2 line output as your required output, so it's hard to understand the relation between the 2, because it looks like you want a multiline block of information, (like an address label), but your example output is (after the header) all on one line. Consider editing your question and using the {} editing tool near the top to improve the description of your required output and logic. GOod luck.

Comment: Do you really need all of those lines of sample input, if possible, please reduce to just the lines that were used to create the output line.

Comment: @shellter I am afraid that is the source file I have and I will not be able to change it soon. 
I tried to separate the things I need when saying first/second..until the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

$1 == x=("Node") {
    c++

    f=sub(/[^,]*,/,"")
    one = (one ? one : x) OFS $0
    next
}

c==5 && $2 !~ /CBMR/ {
    next
}

f==1 {
    y=$1

    gsub(/^[^,]*,|[ \t]*$/,"")
    two = (two ? two : y) OFS $0
    f=0
}

END {
    print one ORS two
}
```

Results:

```
Node,Manufacturer,Model,Name,Version,AddressWidth,SerialNumber,Name,Version
NAKAMA,Dell Computer Corporation,PowerEdge 6650,Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1,5.2.3790,32,BZJS571,CBMR 5.0.1 Release 4,5.0.1
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } $1 == x=("Node") { c++; f=sub(/[^,]*,/,""); one = (one ? one : x) OFS $0; next } c==5 && $2 !~ /CBMR/ { next } f==1 { y=$1; gsub(/^[^,]*,|[ \t]*$/,""); two = (two ? two : y) OFS $0; f=0 } END { print one ORS two }' file
```

Comment: Sorry Steve I am using Gawk for Windows, I launched both ways, one liner and the script but its producing empty information. 
not sure why, I am already escaping the " by \" but still is not working, I will try a few things

Comment: Sorry, for some reason every time I copied the code one character was replaced, used another browser, and it's working fine. 
And this code works as I need, thank you!

Comment: @Eduardo: Wow! Thanks mate! Haven't seen this sort of generosity before! Cheers!